# "ImportError: DLL load failed" when attempting hg serve (Windows)

Tags: mercurial

I am new to Mercurial and just installed EasyMercurial on my Windows 7 machine to learn it. I have created several repositories, and have been successfully making commits and pushes and pulls. However, when I tried the "hg serve" command, the server doesn't start.  This is the error message that I get (debugging turned on in case that helps):

```
PS C:\scripts> hg serve --debugger
entering debugger - type c to continue starting hg or h for help
> c:\scripts\mercurial\dispatch.pyo(87)_runcatch()
(Pdb) c
listening at http://MyMachineName:8000/ (bound to *:8000)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 87, in _runcatch
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 741, in _dispatch
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 514, in runcommand
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 831, in _runcommand
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 802, in checkargs
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 738, in <lambda>
  File "mercurial\util.pyo", line 472, in check
  File "mercurial\commands.pyo", line 5280, in serve
  File "mercurial\cmdutil.pyo", line 533, in service
  File "mercurial\commands.pyo", line 5276, in run
  File "SocketServer.pyo", line 225, in serve_forever
  File "mercurial\demandimport.pyo", line 86, in __getattribute__
  File "mercurial\demandimport.pyo", line 58, in _load
  File "select.pyo", line 12, in <module>
  File "select.pyo", line 10, in __load
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
> c:\scripts\select.pyo(10)__load()
(Pdb)
```

There isn't any kind of "serve" command that I can find on the EasyMercurial UI, so one thought I have is that maybe "hg serve" just isn't supported by what you get with EasyMercurial. But I seem to be able to do everything else using my choice of either the command line or the UI, so it seems to me that this *ought* to work.  Am I wrong or is my install just bad somehow?

Comment: Try executing the same command in an administrator command prompt...

Comment: Good suggestion, but unfortunately, no difference.

Comment: Just kill EasyMercurial and install TortoiseHG

Comment: Yeah, I thought of that myself and confirmed that that indeed is a way to get hg serve to work, but it doesn't really answer the question. Shouldn't hg serve work with just the EasyMercurial install?

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem. I've uninstalled TortoiseHG 4.4.1 and installed 4.3.1 version and it worked.

Link for older versions: https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/files/downloads/