# Unable to open tortoisehg workbench

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I download tortoisehg 4.4.1-x64 in Windows 7, but I am unable to open its workbench. When I try open tortoisehg, I get alert **See the logfile 'C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\thgw.exe.log' for details.**
The error logged in file:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "thg", line 122, in 
  File "hgdemandimport\demandimportpy2.pyo", line 145, in **getattr**
  File "hgdemandimport\demandimportpy2.pyo", line 90, in _load
  File "hgdemandimport\demandimportpy2.pyo", line 41, in _hgextimport
  File "tortoisehg\hgqt\run.pyo", line 391, in 
  File "hgdemandimport\demandimportpy2.pyo", line 145, in **getattr**
  File "hgdemandimport\demandimportpy2.pyo", line 90, in _load
  File "hgdemandimport\demandimportpy2.pyo", line 41, in _hgextimport
  File "tortoisehg\hgqt\qtapp.pyo", line 18, in 
  File "hgdemandimport\demandimportpy2.pyo", line 167, in _demandimport
  File "hgdemandimport\demandimportpy2.pyo", line 41, in _hgextimport
  File "tortoisehg\hgqt\qtcore.pyo", line 53, in 
  File "hgdemandimport\demandimportpy2.pyo", line 167, in _demandimport
  File "hgdemandimport\demandimportpy2.pyo", line 41, in _hgextimport
  File "PyQt5\QtCore.pyo", line 12, in 
  File "PyQt5\QtCore.pyo", line 10, in __load
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

Please let me know if anyone faced this issue and was able to resolve

Comment: checkout bug report https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg/issues/4977/dll-load-failed-after-fresh-install

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["ImportError: DLL load failed" when attempting hg serve (Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23531866/importerror-dll-load-failed-when-attempting-hg-serve-windows)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it is solved by installing Microsoft C++ 2015 Redistributable Update 3.
This file can be downloaded from here https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53587

Comment: For more recent TortoiseHg / Windows installs, it's the combined "Visual Studio 2015, 2017 and 2019" installation that's missing.  Both the x86 and x64 installs must be run, because... well, because Microsoft.  Downloads can be had at https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads

Answer (score -1):

**Step 1:**
search **mercurial.ini** file in C drive

**Step 2**
open the mercurial.ini file and check the [Path] or remove the path url and save.Now reopen the hg application.